# Botão com um valor - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho 2 botões e cada um terá que enviar um valor do modelo e também será o `submit`

<kbd>botão 1</kbd> e <kbd>botão 2</kbd> - dependendo do botão que eu clicar ele vai enviar o valor para o campo @avaliação.tipo. Parecido com um *like* e *dislike*. O possível código imagino que deve ficar na *view* no *helper* `form_for`

[botão 1]:

```
<%= form_for(@avaliacao) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'compartilhado/mensagens_erro', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :item_id %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :avaliacao, placeholder: "Escreva seu Comentario..." %>
    </div>
<!-- Seria isso no f.submit?? -->
    <div class="col-md-4.5 col-md-offset-8">
      <%= f.submit "Avaliar!", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte (não testei na prática):

Crie o campo `@avaliação.tipo` do tipo `hidden`:

```
<%= f.hidden :tipo, id: 'hidden_tipo' %>
```

Torne invisível o submit:

```
<%= f.submit "Avaliar!", class: "..." style='display: none' id='submit' %>
```

Crie os dois botões e use jQuery para mudar o campo hidden e enviar o formulário:

```
$('#botao1').click(function() {
  $('#hidden_tipo').val('like');
  $('#submit').click();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou aqui! Eu achei que teriam dois botões de submit! Bom saber que da para fazer coisas desse tipo!