# Atualizar a tabela do BD ao clicar num elemento <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação mobile usando o jqMobile e em Ruby. Como actualizar uma tabela da Base de Dados através de um click num item de uma lista.

A minha lista é gerada assim:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a">
    <% @listaEntidades.each do |entidade| %>
          <li data-icon="false" class="itemPersonalizacao" id="Entidade_<%= entidade.id%>">
               <a href="#"><%= entidade.nome_entidade%></a>
         </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Agora não sei como fazer para actualizar a tabela da Base de Dados, já pesquisei e penso que a melhor opção seria fazer um form escondido nesta página e associar a ele uma classe, onde iria ter um método no ficheiro jQuery:

```
$('.itemPersonalizacao').click(function(){
    onde podia preencher os campos do form escondido, 
    os quais consigo ter a informação
    e depois faria algo do genero $('.classeForm').submit()
}
```

Agora não sei como escrever esse código do *form* e se está é a melhor opção.

**Update 1:**
Cheguei à conclusão que será melhor fazer um POST ou um PUT ainda não percebi bem a diferença no script, mas não estou a conseguir fazer, depois de muito pesquisar, estou com o pedido assim:

```
var formData = {entidade_id: 3, utilizador_id: 1, quadrado_id: 1};

$.ajax({
    url: '/quadrado_entidades/1',
    type: "PUT",
    data: formData,
});
```

Onde na consola me diz que não consegue verificar a *token authenticity*:

```
Started PUT "/quadrado_entidades/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-01 23:15:53 +0100
Processing by QuadradoEntidadesController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"entidade_id"=>"3", "utilizador_id"=>"1", "quadrado_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
```

**Solução:**

Colocar na *application.html.erb*:

```
<head>
   ...
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

Depois no método do ficheiro do script:

```
$('.itemPersonalizacao').click(function(){
     ...
     var formData = {quadrado_entidade: {entidade_id: idEntidade}, authenticity_token: $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr('content'), commit: "Update Quadrado entidade"};

     $.ajax({
         url: '/quadrado_entidades/' + idEntradaQuadradoEntidade,
         type: "PATCH",
         data: formData
    });
    ...
}
```

**Dica:** Para construir formData vejam na consola do Ruby que parâmetros são passados quando é feito um pedido neste caso de update, se geraram os controladores da tabela com o comando scaffold é bastante fácil ver isso, depois é só construirem de maneira igual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, esse é um jeito de fazer (criar um form oculto e usar jQuery para enviá-lo).

Se tu não quiser que o envio do formulário atualize a página use:

```
<%= form_for (...), data: { remote: true } do |f| do %>
  (...)
<% end %>
```

Porém isso só é possível se tu tiver o *[Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)* ativado (ele vem ativado por *default*, é a gem `jquery-ujs`).

Outra alternativa seria fazer uma requisição POST, usando jQuery, para a rota e com os dados desejados.

Veja também: [Botão com um valor - Ruby on Rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15146/botao-com-um-valor-ruby-on-rails/15163)

---

### Update

*Authenticity token* é um recurso de segurança do Rails. Ele bloqueia requisições não GET a menos que tu envie junto um token de autenticação.

Essa completíssima resposta do Stack-EN dá detalhes sobre: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token

Comment: Obrigado por ter respondido, fiz um update à pergunta, se pode-se ajudar mais um bocadinho ficava agradecido...